# A uniqueness result for a BVP over a semi-infinite interval

Tags: differential-equations

Let $q:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, and consider the ODE
$$u''(x)=q(x)u(x) $$
with the boundary conditions $u(0)=\lim_{x \to \infty} u(x)=0$. Under what conditions on $q$ is $u \equiv 0$ the only solution? I know the result is true  for $q(x) \in \{1,x,x^2\}$, since I have some understanding of exponentials, Airy functions and parabolic cylinder functions. But I'm looking for a stronger result. Thank you!

P.S.
I've also asked this on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2206972/a-uniqueness-result-for-a-bvp-over-a-semi-infinite-interval), and got the answer that any nonnegative $q$ also works. However, I'm still after a more general result (e.g. is the continuity of $q$ sufficient?)

Comment: Continuity of $q$ is certainly not sufficient. For example, if you let $u = \sinh(x) / \cosh(x)^2$, then $u'' / u = - 5 + \tanh(x)^2$ is bounded and continuous.

Comment: @WillieWong Trying $u=\sinh(x)/\cosh(x)^2$ I ended up with $u''/u=-5\text{sech}^2(x)+\tanh(x)^2$. The example is valid nonetheless, thanks!